# How to load one image in android WITH OUT download

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-image, imageurl

know anyone of you how can I use one photo from URL with out download? Because I can have a lot of images and if my application CANT download all of them...
I've found one function on web he how can do this but it don't work.

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I really need that, so have anyone any idea?

Comment: By definition, if the image is on the Internet, to display the image, you need to download it. For example, every image on this Web page was downloaded by your browser. You do not have to save the image to a file, though. There are plenty of [image loading libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) -- I recommend that you use one.

Comment: K... But if in any case I need to download the image can u show me how can I download and delete immediately after I've close my application? And if you can, can you show me just one function with how I can do that?

Comment: Which library did you choose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Picasso lib for downloading image from url:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Example:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```